# How to perform a multivariate multiple regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis

I have 4 dependent categorical variables and 11 independent `variables.im` not been able to write the commands in R using the CRAN's mvtnorm.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you say a little more?  For each of your dependent variables, are there just 2 levels (yes/no) or are there multiple variables (red/blue/green)?

Comment: Why do you want to use package *mvtnorm*? It contains functions for dealing with multivariate normal and t distributions, it does not contain anything directly related to regression.